# How to split a column after pivoting the table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a dataset that originally looks like this

```
ContextID   VariableID  Timestamp   Timestampms Value
    7304693 516 2018-07-11 10:49:36 153 1.00000001335143e-10
    7304693 516 2018-07-11 10:49:36 291 1.00000001335143e-10
    7304693 516 2018-07-11 10:49:36 455 1.00000001335143e-10
    7304693 517 2018-07-11 10:49:36 153 0.00266113295219839
    7304693 517 2018-07-11 10:49:36 291 0.00266113295219839
    7304693 517 2018-07-11 10:49:36 455 0.00236816401593387
    7304693 517 2018-07-11 10:49:36 483 0.00236816401593387
```

I wanted to pivot the dataset for making the `VariableID` as separate columns for which I had to combine the `Timestamp` and `Timestampms` for creating unique values and I did it by

```
data = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', header = 0, parse_dates = [['Timestamp', 'Timestampms']])
data = data.rename(columns={'Timestamp_Timestampms': 'Time'})
data = data.pivot(index= 'Time', columns='VariableID', values='Value')
data = data.reset_index(level=0)
```

and got the following dataframe

```
Time                        516                           517    
2018-07-11 10:49:36 153 1.00000001335143e-10    0.00266113295219839
2018-07-11 10:49:36 291 1.00000001335143e-10    0.00266113295219839
2018-07-11 10:49:36 455 1.00000001335143e-10    0.00236816401593387
2018-07-11 10:49:36 483     nan                 0.00236816401593387
```

Now, I would like some help as to how can I separate the `Time` column into 2 different columns. The first one containing just the date and the second column containing the time followed by the other columns like `516` and `517`.

```
Date          Time_ms
2018-07-11  10:49:36_153
2018-07-11  10:49:36_291
2018-07-11  10:49:36_455
2018-07-11  10:49:36_483
2018-07-11  10:49:36_578
```

Also, I would like to set the `ContextID` column from the original table as the index for the pivoted table and would like to know how can it be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
data = data.rename(columns={'Timestamp_Timestampms': 'Time'})
#added ContextID column
data = data.set_index(['ContextID','Time','VariableID'])['Value'].unstack()
data = data.reset_index()

data[['Time','Time_ms']] = data.Time.str.split(n=1, expand=True)
#python separator for ms is . (altarnative solution)
#data['Time_ms'] = data['Time_ms'].str.replace('\s+', '.')
data['Time_ms'] = data['Time_ms'].str.replace('\s+', '_')

c = ['ContextID','Time','Time_ms']
data = data[c + data.columns.difference(c).tolist()]
data = data.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (data)
   ContextID        Time       Time_ms           516       517
0    7304693  2018-07-11  10:49:36_153  1.000000e-10  0.002661
1    7304693  2018-07-11  10:49:36_291  1.000000e-10  0.002661
2    7304693  2018-07-11  10:49:36_455  1.000000e-10  0.002368
3    7304693  2018-07-11  10:49:36_483           NaN  0.002368
```